# SwiftUI Previews: Cannot preview in this file / failed to launch

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

My macOS project will build and run successfully, but previews fail to load in Xcode with the error message:

***Cannot preview in this file**
Failed to launch com.example.AppName*

The diagnostics data yields a generic error message:

```
FailedToLaunchAppError: Failed to launch com.example.AppName

RemoteHumanReadableError
ProcessError: FBApplicationLaunchTransaction succeeded with no process for com.example.AppName:/tmp/AppName/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/AppName/Products/Debug/AppName.app
```

Within my application's logic, I've included checks against `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"]` to ensure that services unrelated to previews aren't initialized, but every View preview produces the same error message with the same unhelpful diagnostic report.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error turned out to be inclusion of the linker flag `-undefined dynamic_lookup` in the *Other Linker Flags* section of my project's configuration.

My project uses `Bundle(path: "...").load()` to load a framework at runtime, so setting the linker flag in this way allowed it to build without generating *undefined symbol* errors. However, it appears that setting things up in this way also kills SwiftUI previews.

To fix this, I simply removed the linker flag and manually linked the framework I was referencing as a non-embedded dependency. The project still builds, and SwiftUI previews are once again working.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I had this same issue because I changed a SwiftData schema incorrectly.

All I had to do to fix my issue was run once with no schema and then re-add the correct schema.

Comment: Given how opaque the error is, I appreciate you adding on to this. The next time I encounter this problem, I'll know to troubleshoot this too.